# Name of the app which shows colorful Android and sweets in grid

Tags: samsung-galaxy-tab

Can someone help me what is the name of this app? I can't find the name of it. Is it a spyware?

[image: http://cubeupload.com/im/9pd13q.jpg]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not malicious - it's part of an "easter egg" hidden in Android 4.4. You can access it by going into Settings → About and tapping on the "Android Version" quickly 4-5 times. Here is a [demonstration on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=btzsbM-sxiU).

There are also some third-party apps on the Play Store that attempt to extract these easter eggs into portable apps, or use them for boot animations [or daydream animations](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.zhuoweizhang.nyandroid). Whether or not *those* are malicious is difficult to determine definitively, but you could probably hazard something of a guess based on the permissions the app requests.

The easter eggs have been of varying levels of complexity and interactivity. Lollipop's is basically an Android-themed [Flappy Bird clone](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W1nUBe8y6Pg).